# writing the Array.every() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods

I am wondering how you can write the `Array.every()` function yourself, with a for loop. In my example the for loop will print true 5 times for each iteration. How can I make it return true just once **if** all values pass, like the `Array.every()` function?

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(array.every(function(num){return num < 6}))

// the for loop will return true 5 times
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(array[i] < 6)
    console.log(true) 
}
```

Comment: proper implementation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"In my example the for loop will return true 5 times for each iteration."*

No it won't, because the first `return` statement returns immediately without iterating over the rest of the items. So really what you've implemented is a simple version of the [`.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which returns `true` if at least one item matches the condition.

If you just want a simple for loop implementation to test that every item matches the condition, reverse the test logic and return `false` as soon as you find an element that does *not* match. And if no items in the loop fail the test then the loop will complete so return `true` 
afterwards:

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(!(array[i] < 6))
    return false;
}
return true;
```

You may like to take a look at a full implementation of `.every()`: [MDN's `.every()` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill)

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say if i console.log() it will print out 5 times. This is what I needed thank you.